# Remove an element from an array of objects in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react Js. I want to remove an element from the array .,

I have an array which is like ,

```
array = [{ Id: "L0", value="asas"}]
```

So, Now What I have is that this value is in `this.props.array`.

Here I get the id which I should remove, So How can compare that array objects Id and remove that particular.

Because I don't want to mutate that array.

Thanks in advance .

```
onRemoveRow(e, id) {

    }
```

For adding ,

```
 const tempObj = {
                id: 'L' + id,
                technologyId: 0,
                technology: '',
                type: '',
                numberOfQuestions: ''
            }
            const addData = [...this.props.lowData.Low, tempObj];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter to return a new array with the relevant item excluded:

```
const newArray = items.filter(item => item.id !== id)
```

It doesn't matter where you store the array (`state`, redux store etc..).

Here is a small running example of adding and removing items from an array in state:

```js
class Item extends React.Component {
  remove = () => {
    const { id, onRemove } = this.props;
    onRemove(id);
  };

  render() {
    const { text } = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <button onClick={this.remove}>Remove</button>
        <div>{text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { id: 1, text: "item 1" },
      { id: 2, text: "item 2" },
      { id: 3, text: "item 3" }
    ]
  };

  addItem = () => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const { items } = state;
      const newId = uuid();
      const newItem = { id: newId, text: `item ${newId}` };
      return {
        items: [...items, newItem]
      };
    });
  };

  onItemRemove = itemId => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const { items } = state;
      const filteredItems = items.filter(item => item.id !== itemId);
      return {
        items: filteredItems
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add Item</button>
          <hr />
        </div>
        {items.map(item => (
          <Item
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            text={item.text}
            onRemove={this.onItemRemove}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/node-uuid/1.4.8/uuid.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Actually, I don't have my data in the state .

Comment: It doesn't matter. Wherever you manage your data, filter is a way to remove items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a handler to the child component along with the array values. This handler is what will update the data in the redux store

Action

```
const handleRemove =(id) => {
    return {
        type: 'REMOVE',
        id
    }
}
```

Reducers:

```
const ArrayItem =  (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'REMOVE': return state.filter(item => item.Id !== action.id);
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Child

```
onRemove = (id) => {
    this.props.handleRemove(id)
}
```

Comment: Actually Sorry but there is no state for this array.

Comment: where exactly is the array coming from as prop to child.

Comment: Actually I already have that in the store so I take it from there like from mapStateToProps.

Comment: In that case you need to dispatch an action, that updates the state in the store

Comment: Yes, I have to dispatch an action, but here first I want to remove that element and then I will take that array and again I am going to update the store with that array.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate, its better to dispatch an action to remove in the store itself.

Comment: This is what I have planned to do . If you see I have updated the question which has adding

Comment: Okay shubham , thanls for the suggestion, is there any wat how I can do with my current approch ?

Comment: Yes you can simply filter the data like `const newArr = this.props.array.filter(item => item.Id !== id);`

Comment: So, But it will always going to create a new array right ?

Comment: It will create a new array and not mutate the original one. But since you will have this expression in the remove function, it will only be e oxecuted when the remove function is executed

Comment: Yes, So, is it okay to do like this ? I mean I am new to this things in react So, I am asking like will it affect any performace.

Comment: No its okay to filter the data out and thats the best way to do it